# How to dynamically create state, functions, and onChanges to use as props when mapping components?

Tags: reactjs, primereact

## What I'm trying to do

I have a DataTable that I am supplying data to. Columns for the DataTable are created dynamically based on the supplied data. I would like to apply filters to each Column based on what type of data the column contains. For instance, I would like a range filter to be available for numerical data, and a toggle dropdown of unique values to be available for a column that has a list of names. In this question for simplicity I am only assigning DropDown filters in a dynamic fashion.

## Problem I am encountering

I am unable to provide the required props and state for the filter to each Column component in a dynamic fashion.

## My Question

Without the ability to use custom functional components (see below in What I've Tried) in the table:

How can I dynamically create columns which have filters that require their own state and handlers? I have not been able to find a way to do this where the state behaves properly.

## Background on use case

- I have a DataTable which accepts Columns as children

  - https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/datatable
- Columns can be configured to use filters (ie a search box, or dropdown of unique values which can be toggled on and off)
- A filter requires:

  - a filterElement function which returns the JSX for the filter type (IE: If the filter is a dropdown, the filterElement contains a MultiSelect)

    - The filterElement requires

      - A state to keep track of selectedOptions
      - An onChange to modify the selectedOptions

        - The onChange requires

          - A reference to the DataTable

## Example of applying a dropdown filter to a column in a static sense when we know the columns ahead of time

```
export default function DataTableFilterClassTest() {

  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(data); // Data imported from elsewhere
  const dt = useRef(null);
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState(null)

  // Hardcoded some options which are available in the data
  const options = [{ option: 1000 }, { option: 1001 }, { option: 1002 }, { option: 1003 }]

  const onOptionsChange = (e) => {
    // 2nd param 'id' is a reference to the field header this filter applies to
    // Hardcoded for testing purposes
    dt.current.filter(e.value, 'id', 'in')
    setSelectedOptions(e.value)
  }

  const filterElement = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <MultiSelect
          value={selectedOptions}
          options={options}
          onChange={onOptionsChange}
          optionLabel="option"
          optionValue="option"
          className="p-column-filter"
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="datatable-filter-demo">
      <div className="card">
        <DataTable ref={dt} value={tableData} paginator rows={10}
          className="p-datatable-customers"
          emptyMessage="No customers found."
        >
          <Column field="id" header="id" filter filterElement={filterElement} />
        </DataTable>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## The Problem

This works fine in a static case in which we know our columns beforehand, but the problem arises when I try to create columns dynamically based on my data. I do not know how to also create the filterElement and the filterElement's required state and onChange for each dynamic column.

```
// ....

const columnFieldsForMapping = ['id', 'company']

const mappedColumns = columnFieldsForMapping.map((field) => {

  // Need to create a new filterElement
  // filterElement requires its own onChange to modify selected options,
  // and value (a state object, to store the selected options) 

  return (

    <Column key={field} field={field} header={field} filter filterElement={HOW DO I CREATE THIS FOR EACH COLUMN} />

  )
  
})

return (
  <div className="datatable-filter-demo">
    <div className="card">
      <DataTable ref={dt} value={tableData} paginator rows={10}
        className="p-datatable-customers"
        emptyMessage="No customers found."
      >

        {mappedColumns}

      </DataTable>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
```

## What I have tried

### Create a CustomColumn component, extending the Column component

My first solution was to create a CustomColumn functional component which extends PrimeReact's column component. The CustomColumn component would contain the filterElement and its required state and functions. It would return a Column component with the applied filterElement prop. **Unfortunately** I later learned the DataTable can not accept any component except for Column components. It will not accept a react functional component which extends the original Column Component. Here is the github issue which states this is not possible: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/644#issuecomment-790648272

**CustomDropDownColumn.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Column } from 'primereact/column';
import { MultiSelect } from 'primereact/multiselect';

export default function CustomDropDownColumn(props) {

  const [state, setState] = useState([])
  
  const onChange = (e) => {
    props.dt.current.filter(e.value, props.field, 'in')
    setState(e.value)
  }
  
  const filterElement = <MultiSelect
    value={state}
    options={props.options}
    onChange={onChange}
    optionLabel="option"
    optionValue="option"
    className="p-column-filter"
  />

  return (

    <Column field={props.field} header={props.field} filter filterElement={filterElement} />
  )
}
```

**Using the custom dropdown column:**

```
// ....
return (
  <div className="datatable-filter-demo">
    <div className="card">
      <DataTable ref={dt} value={tableData} paginator rows={10}
        className="p-datatable-customers"
        emptyMessage="No customers found."
      >

        <CustomDropDownColumn dt={dt} options={options} field={field}/>

      </DataTable>
    </div>
  </div>
);

// ....
```

### Create a class based component to encapsulate the filter logic. Expose the filterElement from this class and apply it as a prop in the Column component

Next I tried to create a class for each filter type. The filter class will store the filterElement and all of it's required state and functions. My intent was to instantiate a new DropDownFilter class for each column during mapping, and supply its exposed filterElement method to the Column being mapped. This did not work because creating a class this way in React does not mount the class. Because it is unmounted, I am unable to call setState with the DropDownFilter class.

**DropDownFilter.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { MultiSelect } from 'primereact/multiselect';

class DropDownFilter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      selectedOptions: null,
    }
  }

  onOptionsChange = (e) => {
    this.props.dt.current.filter(e.value, this.props.field, 'in');
    this.setState({ selectedOptions: e.value })
  }

  filterElement = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <MultiSelect

          value={this.state.selectedOptions}
          options={this.props.options}
          onChange={this.onOptionsChange}
          optionLabel="option"
          optionValue="option"
          className="p-column-filter"

        />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (null)
  }

}

export default DropDownFilter;
```

**DataTable**

```
// ....

const columnFieldsForMapping = ['id', 'company']

const mappedColumns = columnFieldsForMapping.map((field) => {

    // We will map a drop down filter to each column

    // Get unique values in column to supply to dropdowns
    let options = tableData.map(x => {
      const obj = {}
      obj.option = x[field]
      return obj;
    })
    options = uniq(options)

    // Instantiate instance of DropDownFilter class to use with mapped column
    const newFilter = new DropDownFilter({ dt: dt, field: field, options: options })

    return (

      <Column key={field} field={field} header={field} filter filterElement={newFilter.filterElement} />

    )
  
})

return (
  <div className="datatable-filter-demo">
    <div className="card">
      <DataTable ref={dt} value={tableData} paginator rows={10}
        className="p-datatable-customers"
        emptyMessage="No customers found."
      >

        {mappedColumns}

      </DataTable>
    </div>

  </div>
);
}
```